# SSL enabled Canvas IFrame application loads some URLs using HTTP

Tags: facebook, ssl

I have a IFrame application deployed on Facebook. This morning when I went to the application some of the files, mostly images, were being loaded using http, even though they are relatively pathed in the HTML.

I would understand if all were loaded with http, but am confused as to how only some are. Has anyone else experienced this problem or have any ideas. The site is production, so I disabled https for the time being.

Comment: does your site use your own ssl certificate or you got a ssl proxy hoster?

Comment: I purchased an SSL cert and am using an Amazon EC2 Load Balancer which handles the SSL in front of my app servers.

Answer (score 0):

Its generally best to declare the full web-path to any images in your app.  I only use relative paths in CSS and if that is causing a problem you still may need to specify the full web-path in your CSS files as well.

Why this is happening to you I'm not sure, but I recall some documentation stating that you should always use the full web-path on Facebook apps.